# Negative value returned when only positive integers are used

Tags: c#, math

When running the following code I end up getting negative values. I am only using positive numbers so I am really confused. I have tried to see if this negative number was a return code but there dose not seem to be any codes that return this as a number.

```
  public static int fib(int n)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp + b;
        }

        return b;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 0;
        bool Run = true;

        while (Run == true)
        {
            n = fib(n + 1);
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }
    }
```

Here are the results when the code is run:

```
1
2
3
5
13
610
-121099088
1
```

Comment: Not related, but you could shorten your code by using while(true) instead of the bool ;)

Comment: you could also use the `BigInteger` class, available since 4.0, or look for a similar library if you're using an earlier framework.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments on how to improve my code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're just seeing integer overflow. You're trying to compute `fib(610)` which is way more than an `Int32` can hold - and when you add two large integers together, you'll get a negative number.

If you build it in "checked" mode, an exception will be thrown instead - or you can do it just for the one expression you need:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = checked(temp + b);
}
```

See MSDN for more on [checked arithmetic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx).

Comment: +1 for mention of checked, I've never seen that keyword before.

Comment: Thank you i am still learning c# and instantly though it was a return error code

Answer (score 7):

This is the result of an integer overflow and the use of [twos' complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent integers.

In C#, the default is not to check for integer overflows. If you do change to a [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) context, you will get an exception.

Either use a [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) context, use `uint` or even `ulong` - you need to ensure you are using a data type that can hold the values you are calculating.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is computing the 'nth' Fibonacci number, but it's getting it's 'n' from the previous calculation.  My guess is that the 610th Fibonacci number is overflowing int.  Use unsigned uint or ulong if you want to continue using this logic.  Otherwise, you need to modify how you're determining 'n' for your Fibonacci calculation.